# Run Internal Sharepoint 2013 app on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a scenario where I want to run a internal app which is hosted in on-prem SharePoint 2013 on SharePoint online.

Comment: Have you tried publishing the app into SharePoint online tenancy?

Comment: Nope I havent tried that.